# Reference for a proof of a Theorem by Joseph Wolf

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, manifolds

We know that Lie Groups are parallelizable, I was looking for a version of the converse and came across this:
https://books.google.com/books?id=w4bhBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA115 in Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by John M. Lee (1st edition, Springer, 2003).

As says in the link : a remarkable theorem by Joseph Wolf says that the only compact,simply connected manifolds that  are parallelizable are products of Lie groups and copies of $S^7$

But, I am not being able to find this proof, If anyone can give a proof or a reference that would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

$\textbf{Update} $: As discussed in the comments the following result in Lee's book isn't exactly correct. Anyway these are the Wolf's papers mentioned in the link:

[Wol71] Joseph A. Wolf. On the geometry and classification of absolute parallelisms I. J. Differential Geometry, 6:317-342, 1971. [projecteuclid](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214430496), [author's website](https://math.berkeley.edu/~jawolf/publications.pdf/paper_047.pdf);

[Wol72] Joseph A. Wolf. On the geometry and classification of absolute parallelisms II. J. Differential Geometry, 7:19-44, 1972. [projecteuclid](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214430818), [author's website](https://math.berkeley.edu/~jawolf/publications.pdf/paper_048.pdf)

The original question about conditions which put a multiplicative or a group structure on a parallelizable manifold still remains unanswered. So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't get it... the source you link to specifically references [Wol71] and [Wol72].  Check there.

Comment: In the case you do not have access to the part of the book with the bibliography (for example, if you only have access through Google Books), I have posted below a full quote and also references [Wol71] and [Wol72] mentioned in the above comment. (Of course, it's possible that other users will provide some additional references.)

Comment: Actually, this is a misreading of Wolf's actual result, which was about absolute parallelisms consistent with a given metric, not general parallelizable manifolds.  The claim as made above about them being products of Lie groups and copies of $S^7$ is certainly not correct.  For example, the exotic 7-spheres of Milnor are not products, and, yet, they are parallelizable.  I think this may be why Lee removed this claim in the second edition.

Comment: I see... thanks for the comment

Comment: So are there conditions which make a parallelizable manifold a Lie group...may be gives a multiplicative structure if not a group

Comment: @PSG:  Yes, there are such conditions, but they are not trivial.  Wolf's results are, as I wrote, about 'abolute parallelisms consistent with a (pseudo-Riemannian) metric'.  Wolf's work on this extended (and slightly corrected) the original work of Cartan and Schouten that proved, in the Riemannian case, that compact simply connected examples of such were products of Lie groups and $S^7$.  The key word here is 'consistent', for the definition of which, see Wolf's cited papers.

Comment: @PSG I have edited the Google Books link a bit and also added links to the paper. Feel free to edit the post further if needed.

Comment: Now after all these I am confused about the title. It doesn't make sense now. Any suggestion about it?

Comment: Just a remark. As stated, the "theorem" would imply Poincaré conjecture...

Comment: @PSG:  It would be helpful if you would define what you mean by a 'multiplicative structure', since you clearly don't mean a Lie group structure.  Without knowing what you mean by this, we can't help you.

Comment: I mean the manifold will have a multiplication structure, it will be closed under multiplication and elements will have inverses, my main motivation for this is so that we can apply the left multiplication trick which exactly how we prove that lie groups and $S^7$ is parallelizable

Comment: One more thing. The way Lee put it, it sounds strange anyway. Since he says all compact parallelizable manifolds are...., whereas none of the building blocks G or S^7 may not be compact without boundary. I was also wondering on Lee's statement. I came here looking and now all is clear. Thanks.